# SAS converting text to numeric F12.2 format error

Tags: string, sas, numbers, format

I'm trying to convert a text variable into numeric and then back to text to round it and preserve trailing and leading zeroes so if my number is 0.501 I want to display 0.50 in SAS.

I have come up with this bit of code which works when the text string is longer than 3 digits + but it doesn't work when its just 1 digit

```
test = strip(put(round(input('5',f12.2),0.01),f12.2));
test_2 = input('5',f12.2)
```

Can someone please explain why I end up with 0.05 instead of 5.00 in the above example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is using F12.2 as the INFORMAT.  That 2 says divide the value by 1E2 if the value has no explicit decimal.

```
42   data _null_;
43      length have $12;
44      do have = '5','5.001','500.01';
45         new  = put(round(input(have,f12.),.01),F12.2-l);
46         put '*' new $12. '*' +3 have=;
47         end;
48      run;

*5.00        *   have=5
*5.00        *   have=5.001
*500.01      *   have=500.01
```

Comment: very insightful

Comment: Thanks a lot!, what does the F12.2-l mean?

Comment: -L is a modifier to left justify the formatted value.  The default for numeric variables is right justified by I didn't thank you wanted that because you used STRIP.